# how can I loop on a list that contain a 2 d list in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, 2d

## Input

my_skills = ["HTML",  "CSS", "JS", "Python", ["Flask", "Django"], "MySQL"]

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please take note that StackOverflow is not a Q&A forum. When you ask a Question it should contain at least data, code and the specific coding problem you encounter. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you try any *for* loop first and can post your code and problem here?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here, you need to specify the question. But if I understand you correctly you want to get each element alone.

```
my_skills = ["HTML", "CSS", "JS", "Python", ["Flask", "Django"], "MySQL"]

for skill in my_skills:
    if type(skill) == str:
        print(skill)
        continue
    for skill_in_array in skill:
        print(skill_in_array)
```

A better way to present your skills in the code in my opinion would be:

```
my_skills = {
    "Web" : {
        "HTML",
        "CSS",
        "JS"
    },
    "Web_PY" : {
        "Flask",
        "Django"
    },
    "Backend" : "MySQL"
}
```

and to loop over it you can do:

```
for key in my_skills:
    print(f"{key}: ")
    for value in my_skills[key]:
        print(f"\t{value}")
    print(end="\n")
```